# Object.name == array[element]

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object

Good evening everyone,
I want to start by apologizing upfront for I am a student, who got to this point thanks to you.

Here is my code, well at least the part related to this question:

```
class BlackGlobeCli
  
  attr_accessor :country_one, :country_two, :input_value
  
  def initialize
    @country_one
    @country_two
    @input_value
    
    @greet_array = [
    "Hello, traveler!",
    "Welcome to Black Globe online exchange office! Below is a list of countries and organizations whose currencies we currently work with:"
    ]
    @country_array = [
    "United States",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "Argentina",
    "Australia",
    "Canada",
    "Switzerland",
    "Chile",
    "China",
    "Colombia",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "Egypt",
    "European Union",
    "United Kingdom",
    "Hungary",
    "Israel",
    "India",
    "Mexico",
    "Malaysia",
    "Norway",
    "Poland",
    "Paraguay",
    "Russia",
    "Sweden",
    "Turkey",
    "Taiwan",
    "Ukraine"
    ]
  end
...
end
```

Edit: The API that I am using, holds the currency info of the countries in the list. This is an example of the API:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

# Setting URL
url = "https://prime.exchangerate-api.com/v5/YOUR-API-KEY/latest/USD"
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
response_obj = JSON.parse(response)

# Getting a rate
rate = response_obj['conversion_rates']['EUR']
```

This would return:

```
{
"result":"success",
"documentation":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
"terms_of_use":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
"time_zone":"UTC",
"time_last_update":1581379262,
"time_next_update":1581382982,
"base":"USD",
"conversion_rates":{
    "USD":1,
    "AED":3.6721,
    "ARS":60.7704,
    "AUD":1.4955,
    "BGN":1.7861,
    "BRL":4.3155,
    "BSD":1.0000,
    "CAD":1.3310,
    etc. etc. etc.
    }
}
```

So now, using my `BlackGlobeCli` class, I need to ask user for an input, use that input and create an object of a first currency, ask the user for another input, use that input to create another country object and it's currency and at the and get the input for the amount of money the user wants to exchange and do the exchange.
So, I am stuck at step one (create an object of a first currency).
I hope I explained it better now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, if you want to implement currency exchanger in one class,such as below maybe help.If I misunderstand your question, please comment.

```rb
class CurrencyExchanger

  class CountryNotSupported < StandardError; end

  def initialize(from, to, money)
    [from, to].each { |e| raise CountryNotSupported if supported_countries.exclude? e }
    @from = from
    @to = to
    @money = money
  end

  def supported_countries
    YAML.load_file( '/your_path_to_country_yaml' )
    # set countries in yml file, not initialize values in class explicitly 
  end

  def exchange_rate
    # implement exchange rate depends on @from and @to
  end

  def result
    @money / exchange_rate
  end
end
```